# RestKit 0.2 Digest basic auth

Tags: ios, cocoa, restkit, digest

I'm currently in the process of upgrading RestKit in our ios app to 0.2, I'm attempting to integrate with an API service which uses Digest basic auth. Everything was working before the migration, but now I get 401.

Previously we did the following to set the auth data:

```
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].client.authenticationType =  
RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTPBasic;
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].client.username = @"un";
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].client.password = @"pw";
```

Now as I understand it we should do this

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:url];
[manager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"un" password:@"pw"];
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Ended up adding a different type of authentication server-side which works. Still no solution with digestive auth.